# Copy data through Azure database

Tags: azure, ssms, linqpad

I have two azure database with same schema. I need copy from one table from db1 to table db2. What is the easiest way to do this. I try copy and paste from SQL management studio, but SQLGeografy shows only . I try use linqpad, but Linqpad say SQL Azure does not permit cross-database queries.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way is through SSDT ( Sql Server Data Tools ). You can get it from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Here's a post showing how to compare and synchronize the data of two databases using SSDT:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn266028(v=vs.103).aspx